# What is known about the approximation constant?

Tags: reference-request, approximation, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

A *badly approximable* irrational is one whose continued fraction denominators are bounded; equivalently, if $\alpha$ is badly approximable then there is a $c(\alpha) > 0$ such that
$$c(\alpha) = \liminf_{q \to \infty}q|q\alpha-p|$$
Where $p$ is the nearest integer to $q\alpha$. The constant $c(\alpha)$ is said to be the approximation constant to $\alpha$.

**My question:** what is known about $c(x)$? Do we know its value for particular $x$? The [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BadlyApproximable.html) page has no information on it.

Answer (score 2):

The **approximation constant** $ c ( x ) $ is also known as the **Lagrange constant** (see "*[Markoff–Lagrange spectrum and extremal numbers](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11511-011-0065-z)*" by D. Roy).

Sometimes it is defined as its inverse instead (see "*[The role of the Lagrange constant in some nonlinear waves equations](http://emis.icm.edu.pl/journals/RSMT/57-3/175.pdf)*" by A. K. Ben-Naoum).

An example, which now appears in the Wolfram Mathworld page you mentioned, is $ c ( 1 / \sqrt{5} ) = ( \sqrt{5} - 1 ) / 2 $.